# using the Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

How can I use the **Bottom Navigation bar** (android support widget) for something more than displaying different strings? I mean, **how can I use it to switch between layouts?** didn't found a solution and somehow "`setContentView (R. layout. example);`" doesn't work.

Comment: Set content view is the entire Activity, not the bottom bar... Try using a `LayoutInflater`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/README.md

Comment: If something is not working as expected, please [edit] your question to include your code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick snippet to get started:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomBar mBottomBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Notice how you don't use the setContentView method here! Just
        // pass your layout to bottom bar, it will be taken care of.
        // Everything will be just like you're used to.
        mBottomBar = BottomBar.bind(this, R.layout.activity_main,
                savedInstanceState);

        mBottomBar.setItems(
                new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_recents, "Recents"),
                new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_favorites, "Favorites"),
                new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_nearby, "Nearby"),
                new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_friends, "Friends")
        );

        mBottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(final int position) {
                // the user selected a new tab
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}


How to use ?
```

To begin with we need to update our dependency!

> compile ‘com.android.support:design:25.0.0’

Design xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content Container -->


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Create menu as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_favorites"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_schedules"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_music"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Handling Enabled / Disabled states. Make selector file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

**Handle click events.**

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favorites:
**question now is: what to put inside here so it switch to another layout??** 
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_schedules:
**question now is: what to put inside here so it switch to another layout??** 
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_music:
**question now is: what to put inside here so it switch to another layout??** 
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
});
```

Comment: That's a different component than what is asked about. https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks alot but i already tried this one, but it is not switching more than between strings. Which leads to my question:how can it switch between more than strings? im a blatant noob at this point so i am happy for any help.

Comment: @Belmandel I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Did you mean to respond to Euphor08?

Comment: @Euphor08 thanks alot for the help. i already have my navigation bar set up and stuff, all i need to know is how i can let it switch between layouts because from what i can read in those codes is that it doesnt switch between layouts

Comment: @cricket_007 no i responded to you. i already tried the sample you posted, but it is not switching between layouts..